# How to make dependencies use their own transitive dependencies in JVM languages

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, sbt-assembly

Suppose I have two libraries in my `pom.xml` or `build.sbt`, say A and B.  Suppose they both depend on C, but A depends on version 1 and B depends on version 2.

My understanding is that if these versions are incompatible there is pretty much nothing that can be done, except trying to upgrade/downgrade either A or B such that it depends on the same version of C.

Q1: Surely someone has invented a way to compile A & C.1 such that A calls C.1 and compile B & C.2 such that B calls C.2?

Q2: Is this inherently difficult since java builds from bytecode, rather than source? Q3: So such a tool would have parse and modify the bytecode, rather than just the Java/Scala code?

Q4: Is there a native Java way of doing this (rather than using some independent tool)?

Q5: Are there any other languages/compilers that don't have this problem? (i.e. the feature to make A call C.1 and B call C.2 is native)

Comment: There is no magic solution, check all the transitive dependencies to enforce compatibility, or shade.

Comment: Thats right, in order to A use C1 and B use C2 at the same time, all packages of C1 and C2 must be different.

Comment: @cchantep what exactly is shading? Do you know a good link that explains how it in detail?

Comment: some libraries are backward compatible. You need to check if it fits what you are using.

Comment: Using your favourite search engine you could see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297276/what-is-a-shaded-java-dependency